# frame array of recursive json object from an another array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

i have an array of objects of the below format
each with a unique 'sub-task' entry, each of this sub-task is to be embedded as a children element of each unique 'task' from the 'tasks' array

```js
[
  {
   "sub-task":"abc",
   "task":"alpha1"},
  {
   "sub-task":"def",
   "task":"alpha1"},
   {
   "sub-task":"ijkl",
   "task":"proto"},
   {
   "sub-task":"mno",
   "task":"def"},
  {
   "sub-task":"qrs",
   "task":"proto"},
  {
   "sub-task":"asdf",
   "task":"mno"},
  
  
  
]
```

i was trying to frame an another array of below format

```js
[
   {
      "name":"alpha1",
      "children":[
         {
            "name":"abc"
         },
         {
            "name":"def",
            "children":[
               {
                  "name":"mno"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"proto",
      "children":[
         {
            "name":"ijkl"
         },
         {
            "name":"qrs",
            "children":[
               {
                  "name":"asdf"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

i was trying of below logic, but ended up with no solution...

```js
var treeData = [];
for( var ele of tasks){
  recurOn(treeData,ele);
  
}
function recurOn(arr,obj){
  if(arr.length == 0){
    treeData.push({name:obj.parentGroup,children:[{name:obj.groupName}]})
    //console.log(treeData);
    return 1;
  }else {
    for(var item of treeData){
      if(item.name == obj.parentGroup){
        //console.log('item: ', item);
        item.children.push({name:obj.groupName});
        break;
      }
      else {
        treeData.push(recurOn([],obj))
      }
    }
    return 1;
  }
}
//console.log(treeData);
//console.log(result);
```

Since the no of levels an elements holds is not known i was unable to fix for a logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a map to store object reference.

```js
let input = [
  { "sub-task": "abc", "task": "alpha1" },
  { "sub-task": "def", "task": "alpha1" },
  { "sub-task": "ijkl", "task": "proto" },
  { "sub-task": "mno", "task": "def" },
  { "sub-task": "qrs", "task": "proto" },
  { "sub-task": "asdf", "task": "mno" },
];

let map = new Map, result = [];

input.forEach(({ ["sub-task"]: name, task }) => {
  let node = map.get(task), child = { name, children: [] };
  if (!node) {
    map.set(task, node = { name: task, children: [] });
    result.push(node);
  }
  map.set(name, child);
  node.children.push(child);
})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Can this be achieved using recursion ?

Comment: of course, There is two task, (1) find node , (2) update node, so you can use recursion to find node